# Convert a lisp string to stream

Tags: string, lisp, stream

I have a file that looks like this:

```
A B C D E
0 8 6 12 5
8 0 10 8 9
6 10 0 7 11
12 8 7 0 6
5 9 11 6 0
```

I don't know ahead of time how many rows and columns there will be. I would like to read the top line, which will let me know the number of rows to expect . I found lisp's `(read <stream>)` function which, in a loop, can parse each of the characters as symbols. I have not found a way, however, to limit the loop to only reading the first line and stopping there. The solution I'm trying to make work would be something like

```
(with-open-file (stream "/home/doppler/tmp/testcase1.txt")
  (setf line (read-line stream))
  (when line
    (loop for symbol = (read line nil)
         while symbol do (print symbol))))
```

The problem with this is that `(read-line stream)` returns a string which cannot be parsed by `(read line nil)` to extract the symbols (s-expressions).

How can I either convert the string line to a stream, or, if possible, extract the symbols directly from the string?

Comment: `make-string-input-stream`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use the string as a stream by using the [`with-input-from-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_in_f.htm#with-input-from-string) macro, or use [`read-from-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_fro.htm#read-from-string) in a loop.  You may also be interested in the [`read-delimited-list`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_del.htm#read-delimited-list) function, although you would have to add some kind of delimiter character to the end of the string before using it.

Comment: I ended up using the read-from-string. The read-delimited-list function looks useful, but I haven't quite gotten used to reading the LISP documentation yet so I'm not quite sure how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `sb-ext:string-to-octects` which allow me to specify the external format as utf-8.   I was surprised since the default format should be utf-8 according to https://www.sbcl.org/manual/#The-Default-External-Format.  I guess the internal format is iso-8859-1.

I ended up with

```
(test base64-3
      (is (string= "YWJjZMKj" (cl-base64:usb8-array-to-base64-string
                               (sb-ext:string-to-octets "abcd£" :external-format :utf-8)))))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Lisp has a number of libraries that can handle various tasks. The str library would help in this case.

```
* (str:words "A B C D E")
("A" "B" "C" "D" "E")
```

Documentation for str can be found through the Common Lisp Cookbook in the Strings section: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html

If you find you get an error that str is not available, use (ql:quickload "str") to get the library.